# Insert data from textfile to a database table

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I would like to ask some help in inserting data from `texfile` to a database table....i created a php code to execute in inserting the files to the table but i have no luck in importing it...can anyone know to do this?help me please.

[image]

current php code:

```
<?php
$host= "localhost";
$user= "root";
$pass= "";
$db="klayton";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$connect)die ("Cannot connect!");
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

$file = fopen("tblApplicants.txt","r");  

while( $applicants = fgets($file) )
{
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_applicants( aic,name ) VALUES ('$applicants')"; 
  mysql_query($sql);
}    
?>
```

Comment: Why not use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) or [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each line from this file,skip every second line  $i%2 == 0  do break;
explode it at " | " and get  second ( $row[1] ) and nextone ( $row[2] ), then trim it, and make sql insert.
Try to do at this way